# How can I change the highlight color in the Visual Studio 2012 error list?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes

I'm using the Dark theme from the Visual Studio 2012 themes. I have installed the VS 2012 color theme editor.  What I want to do is change the background color that appears in the Error list when you select an error.

Presently that background color is a highly saturated bright blue.  Text for errors is white.  The white on bright blue is difficult to read.  I want to tone that blue down. But I can't locate the property in the color theme editor that will adjust that.  What color attribute can I adjust in the editor to change that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the theme editor, select "Show all elements".

Then edit "Environment -> Highlight".

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You are correct. My apologies for the delayed reply. I had forgotten about this.

Comment: Can you tell where the "Theme Editor" is to be found? I only found in the Menu "Tools > Options" then in the Dialog "Environment > Fonts and Colors", but there is neither an option "Show all elements", nor settings for the Error List.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when finding and replacing strings with the Visual Studio 2013 Dark Theme. The search would highlight all the found items light blue. When I went to select a part of the highlighted string, it would highlight the selected portion with a nearly identical color making it very difficult to tell what part of the string was highlighted for edit.

I went into TOOLS -> Options... -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor -> Selected Text and changed it to 'Yellow' which is working well for me.

Comment: Thanks! Maroon works better for me as visual merges the two background colors and with yellow it is harder to read the selected text, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

If it's anything like Visual Studios 2010:

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors -> Display Items(Error)

Comment: That's not it, but thanks for the suggestion.  The dialog still exists in VS 2012, but that selection leads to red text on black background.  I also tried Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Output Window (dropdown) > Current List Location. But that didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following the following list of menus:

`Tools -> Options... -> Fonts and Colors -> Text Editor -> Find Match Highlight`

Comment: Add some more detailed description